# Using AWS Device Farm with JUnit 5

Tags: amazon-web-services, junit, aws-device-farm

I've found that when I upload my JUnit 5 tests to AWS fails because [it expects to find a dependency in the format `junit-<ver>.jar`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting-appium-java-junit.html?icmpid=docs_devicefarm_console#APPIUM_JAVA_JUNIT_TEST_PACKAGE_JUNIT_VERSION_VALUE_UNKNOWN). However, [JUnit 5 has changed the package names](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata) to `org.junit.jupiter.ap` and `org.junit.platform.commons`.

Does this mean that AWS Device Farm doesn't support JUnit 5? Are there any plans to support it soon?

Comment: I can confirm that switching to JUnit 4 fixes the issue. Can't seem to find any information about when AWS DF will start supporting JUnit 5 (but it's an awkward one to search for, most results concern JUnit 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Device Farm doesn't support JUnit 5. I will create a feature request for you.

Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate it

Comment: any news regarding support? its really weird it does not support it still

Comment: Device Farm has a new feature called custom environment which enables you to use any test framework you like.

For more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html